# Find and format strings in over 500 readme.md files using bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I'm working on a project where I'm formating over 500 readme files. Each file contains the following (including the whitespace) and I'd like to make a bash script for the task. I successfully used bash to create all the readme files from data, but I'm having trouble trying to find a way use `sed`, `grep`, and `regexs` to make this work.

**WHAT THE FILE LOOKS LIKE NOW:**

```
"1.0.0": "text1"
  "1.1.15": "text2"
  "2.1.2": "text3"
  "4.55.3a": "text4"
```

**WHAT I WANT IT TO LOOK LIKE:**

```
**v4.55.3a**
 - text 4

**v2.1.2**
 - text 3

**v1.1.15**
 - text 2

**v1.0.0**
 - text 1
```

**BASH SCRIPT (this will format the strings in the files):**

```
f=$(find . -type f -name README.md)
for item in $f; do
  #format version
  #format string
done
```

So pretty much I'm looking for some help on building a script that'll format the contents. Thanks everyone for your input.

**UPDATES**
Are all lines but the 1st in the input files really indented?
- Some are, some aren't.
Do you really want the version numbers enclosed in ** in the output?
- Yes, its for the github markup.
Looks like you want the output files sorted by version number in descending order, correct?
- Correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the input and output formatted exactly as currently specified in the question:

```
tac "$item" | awk -F\" '{ printf "**v%s**\n - %s\n", $2, $4 }' > "/tmp/$item" &&
  mv "/tmp/$item" "$item"
```

Note:

- This assumes that simply *reversing* the input order is sufficient to get the desired output sorting [since confirmed by the OP] - if true sorting is needed, it gets trickier
  (`sort -t. -r -b -n -k1.2,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 "$item"`).
- On OSX, use `tail -r` instead of `tac`.

Also, it's better not to parse command output with `for ... in`, as that would break with paths with embedded spaces, for instance.

A more robust solution is to read into an *array*:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a files <<<"$(find . -type f -name README.md)"
for item in "${files[@]}"; do
   # ...
done
```

- The only caveat is that paths mustn't contain embedded newlines, but that's typically not a concern.
- If you're using bash 4+, you can use `readarray -t files <<<"$(find . -type f -name README.md)"` instead.

Alternatively, process `find`'s output directly in a loop:

```
find . -type f -name README.md -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' item; do ...
```

Comment: `tac` does not sort it by version number, just reverse it. `Looks like you want the output files sorted by version number in descending order, correct?
- Correct!`

Comment: Also, is simply reversing the input sufficient to get the right output order? Yes.

Comment: @SJAndersonLA: Just updated the answer with how to replace the input file after reformatting. `| tee tempt.md1` outputs to _both_ stdout _and_ to file `tempt.md1`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you my like some like this:

```
sort -r -k1 file | awk -F\" '{print "**v"$2"**\n -"$4"\n"}'
**v4.55.3a**
 -text4

**v2.1.2**
 -text3

**v1.1.15**
 -text2

**v1.0.0**
 -text1
```

It revers sort the data based on version number, then print it out in groups.

Comment: The `sort` command doesn't work as intended; adding `-b` would help with the leading whitespace, but that still won't perform true _version-number_ sorting. To make this work properly, you'd need the somewhat byzantine `sort -t. -r -b -n -k1.2,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 file`